# Enable WebDAV in htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, webdav, plesk

Is it possible to enable WebDAV within an `.htaccess` file?

My problem is Plesk. It doesn't parse in my changed config files with the enabled WebDAV.

So, is it possible to enable WebDAV out of an `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `Location` container and the `DAV On` directive to enable it, provided that `mod_dav` is installed on your server:

```
<Location /public/webdav/>
    DAV On
    php_admin_flag engine off
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Options +Indexes
</Location>
```

I suggest that you also incorporate password protection using [mod_auth](http://perishablepress.com/htaccess-password-protection-tricks/).

*PS: If the `Location` container does not work for you, try using `Directory` instead.*

Comment: So u mean i can just copy that stuff and place it in an htaccess?

Comment: You would obviously need to make sure that your directory is correct... But yes, it should work. Provided that the extension is installed on your server.

Comment: You can't do this in an `.htaccess` file, like the question is asking. This would need to go in the server config / VirtualHost - which is what the OP is trying to avoid. (The `AllowOverride` directive is only permitted in a `<Directory>` container.)